# Add Gesture Recognisers to SKSpriteNode

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a requirement where my view object must detect various actions like Tap, Swipe, pinch, Pan.

How can i add gesture recognisers on a `SKSpriteNode object`? Is it even possible?

Comment: You don't directly add gesture recognizers to a SKSpriteNode. You can apply actions to a SKSpriteNode of your choice based on what gestures are recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. The SKNode class has nifty UITouch methods.

```
- (CGPoint)locationInNode:(SKNode *)node;
- (CGPoint)previousLocationInNode:(SKNode *)node;
```

---

For example

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    CGPoint beganT = [[touches anyObject]locationInNode:self];
    //do something
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    CGPoint draggedT = [[touches anyObject]locationInNode:self];
    //do something
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    CGPoint endedT = [[touches anyObject]locationInNode:self];
    //do something
}
```

Be sure you have userinteraction enabled!

```
[self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: This answer seems to neither be about Gesture Recognizers nor about adding them directly on an SKSpriteNode.